# i have a problem with connection string

Tags: .net, asp.net, ado.net, web-config, connection-string

An exception is thrown when i try to login:

> Cannot open database "aspnetdb" requested by the login. The login failed.
>   Login failed for user 'DIMA-00AA1DA557\Dima'.
>
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot open database "aspnetdb" requested by the login. The login failed

My Web.config:

```
<system.web>
    <roleManager enabled="true" />    
    <membership defaultProvider="MyMembershipProvider">
        <providers>
            <clear/>
            <add
                name="MyMembershipProvider"    
                type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider"      
                connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer"         
                requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"      
                minRequiredPasswordLength="1"          
                minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0"
                enablePasswordReset="true"
                maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="1000"
                passwordAttemptWindow="4000"
                enablePasswordRetrieval="true"
                requiresUniqueEmail="false"
                passwordFormat="Encrypted" 
            />         
        </providers>
    </membership>
</system.web>
```

My connection string section

```
<connectionStrings>
    <clear />
    <add name="LocalSqlServer"
        connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Integrated Security=SSPI; Initial Catalog=aspnetdb" />
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
    <add name="YourGuruDB"
        connectionString="Data Source=DIMA-00AA1DA557;Initial Catalog=model;Integrated Security=True"/>
    <add name="modelConnectionString"
        connectionString="Data Source=DIMA-00AA1DA557;Initial Catalog=model;Integrated Security=True"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    <add name="LocalSqlServer2"
        connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename='D:\Documents and Settings\Dima\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\WebSite10\App_Data\ASPNETDB.MDF';Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    <add name="MyLocalSQLServer"
        connectionString="Initial Catalog=aspnetdb;data source=localhost;Integrated Security=SSPI;" /> 
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: So does aspnetdb exist ? Do the identity running ASP .NET have access to it ? (You are specifying integrated security in the connection string).

Comment: Formatt your question by editing it, not in answer

Comment: yes it does exist. The problem was when i try to put the connection string into the question, it wont let it, it wont display it..so i put it in the answer

Comment: i dont know what i have, i was told that that connection string belongs to aspnetdb.

Answer (score 1):

You use windows authentication in web application. Web application use IIS account to run the code and it does not have enoght rights to open the db. There are two ways to fix the issue:

1. Use sql server authentication
2. Add rights to IIS user to work with
   db.

Comment: How do i do that? and what do i insert where?